# Solve a System of Differential Equations using" bvp4c" Matlab fuction , Error -->Error using bvp4c Too many input arguments

Tags: matlab

I had a hard time trying to run a code of  Differential Equations  using" bvp4c" Maltab function,always geting the same error " Error using bvp4c Too many input arguments" I've tried too many other codes from different works but the result is the same! any help please? The code is shown below:

```
function bvp4c
L=0.2;
xlow=0;
xhigh=L;
solinit=bvpinit(linspace(xlow,xhigh,20),[1 -1]);
sol=bvp4c(@bvp4ode,@bvp4bc,solinit);
xint=linspace(xlow,xhigh);
sxint=deval(sol,xint);
plot(xint,sxint(1,:))
%-----------------
function dydx=bvp4ode(x,y)
L=0.2;
V=1;
E0=8.85e-12;
Er1=2.64;
Er2=3.25;
K11=6.95e-12;
AE=Er2-Er1;
Vth=pi*(K11/(E0*AE))^1/2;
dydx=[y(2) (V^2/Vth^2)*(pi^2/L^2)*sin(y(1))*cos(y(1))];
%-----------------
function res=bvp4bc(ya,yb)
res=[ya(1) yb(1)];
```

Answer (score 0):

You define a function `bvp4c` and inside that function you try to call the built-in MATLAB `bvp4c` function. This does not work. When you define a function that has the same name as a built-in function, MATLAB uses only your function. That is why you have an error `Too many input arguments`: your `bvp4c` function has no input arguments, while inside you call it with three arguments.

To solve this problem, rename your function to e.g. `callBvp4c` or any other name which is not used by MATLAB. Further, make sure that you also rename the file to `callBvp4c.m`, as MATLAB addresses functions via their name.

I assume that all three functions are saved in the same .m file. This is generally possible, but then `bvp4ode` and `bvp4bc` will only be visible *inside* `callBvp4c`. When you call `sol=bvp4c(@bvp4ode,...)`, you give a function handle to the `bvp4c` function, but it won't find the corresponding function. That is what the error says: it doesn't find `bvp4ode`. To solve this, you will have to create a separate .m file for every function and make sure the .m file has the same name as the function. In your case: `callBvp4c.m`, `bvpode.m` and `bvp4bc.m`.

Comment: Thank you hbadert, 

Im still having errors, this time was: 

Undefined function 'bvp4ode' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Error in bvparguments (line 106)
    testODE = ode(x1,y1,odeExtras{:});

Error in bvp4c (line 130)
[n,npar,nregions,atol,rtol,Nmax,xyVectorized,printstats] = ...

Error in callBvp4c (line 6)
sol=bvp4c(@bvp4ode,@bvp4bc,solinit);

Comment: Are all three functions defined in one file?

Comment: Okay, I added a paragraph to the answer which should solve this problem

Comment: Hello hbaderts,

This what I did, I made a folder contains the three files:callBvp4c.m, bvpode.m and bvp4bc.m., for  bvpode.m and bvp4bc.m., I wrote inside the files function bvpode  and function  bvp4bc, while for callBvp4c I have used it to run the code after setting the path. However, unfortunately I got the same errors.I do not know If I follow your procedure precisely.